# GRAILS: creating domain class objects out of (nested) JSON

Tags: json, grails, grails-orm

is there a groovy way to create Grails-Objects out of JSON recursively?

Example

```
class Person {String name, String surname  ....}


class Text { String content, Person owner }
```

What is the easiest way to create objects from the following JSON:

```
{
   "class":"Text",
  "content":"test test test",
  "owner":{
     "class":"Person",
     "id":1
  }
}
```

or even out of:

```
{
   "class":"Text",
  "content":"test test test",
  "owner":{
     "class":"Person",
     "name":"foo",
     "surname":"bar"
  }
}
```

A simple creation (without nested classes) works like charm with:

```
Person p = new Person(JSON.parse(responseBody))
```

Another question is: if a nested creation is not possible, how can i modify the deserialization process?

Currently i avoid the problem through manual assignment:

```
def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( element.toString() )
Person.get(jsonObj.owner.id)
```

It would be nice if there were an generic approach.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it before, but I imagine you could use reflection.

```
def myClass = Class.forName("${owner.class}")
def classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
def myDomain = (myClass, true, classLoader).newInstance())
```

edit: left out an ending parenthesis